# Discord Node.js bot Log recieved messages to console

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm not really experienced with discord.js and node.js but I want to know how I log DMs being sent to the bot to the console. This is the code I'm using to send messages to different people.

```js
case 'senddm':
  mention = msg.mentions.users.first();
  msg.delete();
  if (mention == null) { return; }
  mentionMessage = msg.content.slice(9);
  mention.sendMessage(mentionMessage);
  console.log(`Send message: ${mentionMessage}`)
break;
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: check your `package.json` file

Comment: I found this in "Package.json"
discord.js@11.5.1

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors with the code I have. I just want to know how I can log DMs my bot gets to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your the id of the mentioned user is the same as your bot.

```js
case 'senddm':
  mention = msg.mentions.users.first();
  msg.delete();
  if (mention == null) { return; }
  mentionMessage = msg.content.slice(9);
  mention.sendMessage(mentionMessage);

  if(mention.id === "your bot id here"){
      console.log(`Send message: ${mentionMessage}`)
  }
break;
```

Comment: I do not really know where you got that from but I just want to know how I can log DMs that my bot gets to the console